# Nagios Disable service check if host unreachable

Tags: nagios, service, web, interface, host

When I've declared the host, I specified a command to check if my host is alive (simple ping) :

```
hostgroups              hostgroup-WIN
check_interval          1
retry_interval          1
max_check_attempts      3
check_command           check-host-alive
check_period            24x7
contact_groups          contact-WIN
```

I also got a bunch of services that monitor this server.

**I want to disable theses services when the host is down (the command "check-host-alive" failed), since, of course, all services will lead to an error and to some annoying display on the web interface**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is the default behavior; services have implicit dependencies on their hosts.

This is why you don't get notifications for services on hosts that are down. They will still show in the web interface, though.

You can apply filters, at the top, to only show services on hosts that are up.

Comment: Thank you sir.
For the ones wondering : click on "Services (Unhandled)" 
then, at the top, "Host Status Totals : Up"

Answer (score 2):

Service checks are still being run, it's just the notifications that get suppressed. Since nagios 4.1.1 you can disable service checks by adding `host_down_disable_service_checks=1` to `nagios.cfg`.

Source: https://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=35580